# YouTube Data API invideoPromotion websiteLinkNotAllowed - which links are accepted?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

When I tried adding invideoPromotion to my test channel I kept getting the 403 error which I interpreted to be the 'websiteLinkNotAllowed' case. Changing the URL of the element to twitter.com worked fine co my suspicion is the URL I provided (to my own website) was the problem. However, I couldn't find a description which URLs are allowed and which aren't. Do those links work only with YouTube itself and YouTube partners? Is it possible to whitelist a specific URL?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your website on Google webmaster tools first, then include it as a "linked" website in the channel advanced settings ...
Hope this help